# After clicking image button C# Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My package is vs2010 and my Web dev project in C# asp.net., Im using calendar control by clicking of image button.After that im click that button the other text values are loses. how can i retain that text box values. here im using input textbox not asp textbox.

Comment: can you copy your code here

Comment: Can you post your button_click and page_load code-behind things